Some tag suggestions

snowflake should be renamed to "snowflake-method". The tag name should be telling and not leave users guessing what it refers to.

myersbriggs should be renamed to "myers-briggs". The authors' names are Myers and Briggs, not Myersbriggs.

plot-structure should be merged with plot. A plot is a structure, and it is impossible to discuss plot without discussing its structure.

confusing should be merged with clarity. The one is implied by the other. There are only two questions under the "confusing" tag. One asks how to avoid confusing the reader, which is just another way of asking how to create clarity. The other asks about how to keep information from the reader. For this question we should...

...create an unreliable-narrator tag.

book-rec should be deleted because asking for book recommendations is off topic on this site. If we keep it, it should be renamed to "book-recommendations".

Could someone please approve or reject the pending edit to the stream-of-consciousness tag?




Renamed (with synonym)
Renamed to myers-briggs-type-indicator (with synonyms)
Disagree. Not all plot questions are about plot structure. For example, questions about plot holes should be tagged plot whereas questions about the 3 act structure should be tagged with plot-structure and maybe also [plot] (and 3-acts, etc.)
Done
Done. However, you (as a user with sufficient rep) can create tags by yourself
Until all the questions asking for book recs are gone, it makes sense to keep the tag. However, it does make sense to spell the name out completely (done)
Done


Thank you. I didn't want to create the unreliable-narrator tag and apply it to the question before the issue had been discussed here. And I understand keeping the plot-structure tag.
